# What Consul API to use to query list of services?

Tags: service-discovery, consul

I have a service that needs to query a list of service from Consul.
However I don't need this service to be registered in Consul.
What API should I use then?
Do I need to use client agent or it's ok to query Consul servers directly?

Answer (score 1):

From: https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/http/health.html
(and verified in our usage), you'd query with:

http[s]://:/v1/catalog/services